# Infinite field $F$ with at least two finite subfield

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Can you give an example of infinite field $F$ such that $F$ has at least two finite subfield?

Comment: What examples of infinite characteristic $p$ fields do you know?

Comment: I think $\mathbb{Z}_3(x)$ is infinite but characteristic of this ring is 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the field of rational functions of $\mathbb{F}_q(X)$, where $q=p^n, n>1$. We have $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ for all $k \mid n$ as finite subfields.

Comment: I think your second sentence is not quite right; since we will only have $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ as a subfield for those $k$ with $k\mid n$. (indeed, note that, if $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ is a subfield of a finite field $F$, then $F$ is in particular a finite dimensional $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ vector space and thus has cardinality $p^{lk}$ for some $l$.) but, the example still works! :) (+1)

Comment: You're absolutely right, I have edited my post accordingly! Moreover, it was wrong of me to claim that the subfields were nested in one single tower of fields.

Answer (score 3):

Take the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$. It contains $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ for all $n$. It's infinite for a similar reason.